# Pass Parameter to Session MVC EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have the following controller which is to Filter a View on a table:

```
public ActionResult Index(string asset, string tahun, string bulan)
    {
        var stands = db.MasterCompanies.ToList();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = from s in stands
                                                 select new SelectListItem{Value = s.CompanyID,Text = s.CompanyID + " -- " + s.CompanyName.ToString()};

        ViewBag.asset = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.bulan = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x =>
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[x - 1] + " (" + x + ")",
                Value = x.ToString()
            }), "Value", "Text");

        var masterAPs = db.MasterAPs.Include(m => m.MasterCompany)
                        .Include(m => m.MasterDepartment).Include(m => m.MasterLocation)
                        .Include(m => m.MasterRoom).ToList()
                        .Where(c => c.CompanyID == asset && c.Year == tahun && c.Month == bulan);
        return View(masterAPs);
    }
```

I want to pass the parameter to a session, so I can use it on the other pages.
How can I achieve this? Really appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a session variable like `session["VarName"]=`masterAPs
Then in order to use in other pages get the values from the session like

```
var temp=(classType)session["VarName"]
```

Comment: how can I get the selected value from Dropdownlist which is I put it on ViewBag like my code above?

Comment: In order to get the viewbag values in all the pages create session varaibles for that also.